# details of std::make_index_sequence and std::index_sequence

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm enjoying ramping up on variadic templates and have started fiddling about with this new feature. I'm trying to get my head around the implementation details of `std::index_sequence`'s (used for tuple implementation). I see sample code around there, but I really want a dumbed down step by step explanation of how an `std::index_sequence` is coded and the meta programming principal in question for each stage.  Think *really* dumbed down :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> I see sample code around there, but I really want a dumbed down step by step explanation of how an index_sequence is coded and the meta programming principal in question for each stage.

What you ask isn't exactly trivial to explain...

Well... `std::index_sequence` itself is very simple: is defined as follows

```
template<std::size_t... Ints>
using index_sequence = std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Ints...>;
```

that, substantially, is a template container for unsigned integer.

The tricky part is the implementation of `std::make_index_sequence`. That is: the tricky part is pass from `std::make_index_sequence<N>` to `std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2, ..., N-1>`.

I propose you a possible implementation (not a great implementation but simple (I hope) to understand) and I'll try to explain how it works.

Non exactly the standard index sequence, that pass from `std::integer_sequence`, but fixing the `std::size_t` type you can get a reasonable `indexSequence`/`makeIndexSequence` pair with the following code.

```
// index sequence only
template <std::size_t ...>
struct indexSequence
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper : public indexSequenceHelper<N-1U, N-1U, Next...>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = indexSequence<Next ... >; };

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequence = typename indexSequenceHelper<N>::type;
```

I suppose that a good way to understand how it works is follows a practical example.

We can see, point to point, how `makeIndexSequence<3>` become `index_sequenxe<0, 1, 2>`.

- We have that `makeIndexSequence<3>` is defined as `typename indexSequenceHelper<3>::type` [`N` is `3`]
- `indexSequenceHelper<3>` match only the general case so inherit from `indexSequenceHelper<2, 2>` [`N` is `3` and `Next...` is empty]
- `indexSequenceHelper<2, 2>` match only the general case so inherit from `indexSequenceHelper<1, 1, 2>` [`N` is `2` and `Next...` is `2`]
- `indexSequenceHelper<1, 1, 2>` match only the general case so inherit from `indexSequenceHelper<0, 0, 1, 2>` [`N` is `1` and `Next...` is `1, 2`]
- `indexSequenceHelper<0, 0, 1, 2>` match both cases (general an partial specialization) so the partial specialization is applied and define `type = indexSequence<0, 1, 2>` [`Next...` is `0, 1, 2`]

Conclusion: `makeIndexSequence<3>` is `indexSequence<0, 1, 2>`.

Hope this helps.

**--- EDIT ---**

Some clarifications:

- `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` are available starting from C++14
- my example is simple (I hope) to understand but (as pointed by aschepler) has the great limit that is a linear implementation; I mean: if you need `index_sequence<0, 1, ... 999>`, using `makeIndexSequence<1000>` you implement, in a recursive way, 1000 different `indexSequenceHelper`; but there is a recursion limit (compiler form compiler different) that can be less than 1000; there are other algorithms that limits the number of recursions but are more complicated to explain.

Comment: A good answer, but I would add there's a reason some implementations you might find are quite a bit more complicated: they attempt to reduce the number and/or depth of template instantiations, because there can be a compiler limit to the depth of recursive instantiations, and reducing the total number could make compile times faster.

Comment: THANK you! Thats great. Exactly what I was after.

Comment: @aschepler - I know, I know... I usually (in C++11) use a different implementation with logarithmic complexity. But my intention was make it simple to understand. Maybe I'll try to explain this point a little better...

Comment: @max66 Yes, this simple explanation is definitely more appropriate to the question. Just suggesting some extra info.

Comment: @user3613174 - added a couple of clarifications (see also the aschepler's comment).

Comment: @aschepler - I've tried (but the problem is that I know C++ better than english; I don't know if is comprehensible)

Answer (score 37):

For the sake of completeness, I'll add a more modern implementation of `std::make_index_sequence`, using `if constexpr` and `auto`, that make template programming a lot more like "normal" programming.

```
template <std::size_t... Ns>
struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
auto make_index_sequence_impl() {
    // only one branch is considered. The other may be ill-formed
    if constexpr (N == 0) return index_sequence<Is...>(); // end case
    else return make_index_sequence_impl<N-1, N-1, Is...>(); // recursion
}

template <std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = std::decay_t<decltype(make_index_sequence_impl<N>())>;
```

I strongly advise to use this style of template programming, which is easier to reason about.

Comment: Interesting... yes, with `if constexpr` become simpler. But you should precise that `if constexpr` is available starting from C++17.

Answer (score 4):

Lest it be forgotten:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ...I>
constexpr auto make_index_sequence_impl() noexcept
{
  if constexpr (!N)
  {
    return std::index_sequence<I...>();
  }
  else if constexpr (!sizeof...(I))
  {
    return make_index_sequence_impl<N - 1, 0>();
  }
  else if constexpr (N >= sizeof...(I))
  {
    return make_index_sequence_impl<N - sizeof...(I), I..., sizeof...(I) + I...>();
  }
  else
  {
    return []<auto ...J>(std::index_sequence<J...>) noexcept
    {
      return std::index_sequence<I..., sizeof...(I) + J...>();
    }(make_index_sequence_impl<N>()); // index concatenation
  }
}

template <size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = decltype(make_index_sequence_impl<N>());
```

Comment: can you please add some explanation to the above implementation? It appears to recurse with ```log(N)``` depth.

Comment: it's based on doubling the amount of indices, if possible, so it finishes pretty quick.

Comment: This was very helpful to write a reverse index sequence.