# error: 'this' is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, constexpr

I have constexpr object constructor with constexpr methods.

```
// My SparseArray implementation

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, uint64_t size>
class SparseArray 
{
    public:
    using ElementType = T;

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr SparseArray(Args&&... args) 
    : values{args...} {
        std::cout << "Args ctor." << '\n';
    }

    template<uint8_t Index>
    constexpr ElementType get() const {
        // some logic
        return T();
    }

    constexpr auto someMethod() {
        get<0>();                                            // <--------- works fine
        auto seq  = std::integer_sequence<ElementType, 0>{}; // <--------- works fine
        auto seq2 = std::integer_sequence<ElementType, get<0>()>{}; // <-- error
    }

    ElementType values[size];  
};

int main ()
{
    SparseArray<int, 3> array(1, 2, 3);
    array.someMethod();

    return 0 ;
}
```

[Run code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mrrOBClnrfBE4LBD)

But I really need to use method in such compile-time context.
I'm going to sum two constexpr objects in compile-time, so I need to get data of both thanks to **get** method.

**=======Edited=====**

After @chris answer I understood that I missed one thing.
Actually **get** method looks like this:

```
    template<uint8_t Index>
    constexpr ElementType get() const {
        if(/*some logic*/)
            return values[/*some logic*/];
        else
            return T();
    }
```

So, the code deals with data member of the object.

Comment: `index_sequence<const_values_only>{}` it seems const values only be passed in angle bracket of index_sequence here, in the line `auto seq2 = std::integer_sequence<ElementType, get<0>()>{};`, check for reference it might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669958/details-of-stdmake-index-sequence-and-stdindex-sequence

Comment: now I see `const_values_only`. thank you. but I don't now what to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constexpr` functions have to be usable at compile-time and runtime. You're calling a non-static member function, so it needs to work regardless of whether the class object is known at compile-time. If you require the object to be known at compile-time, the function no longer works at runtime.

The easiest way around this is to use a function that doesn't depend on the unused class object:

```
template<uint8_t Index>
static constexpr ElementType get() {
    // some logic
    return T();
}
```

If that isn't an option because you are using the class object, then you need to ensure that object is constexpr to use it:

```
constexpr SparseArray<int, 3> array(1, 2, 3);
auto seq2 = std::integer_sequence<int, array.get<0>()>{};
```

Regardless of where you use `get`, the only way the result is going to be usable as a compile-time value is if all parameters, including the object, are compile-time values.

EWG has accepted [`constexpr!`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1073r0.html) to force compile-time evaluation of a function, but it wouldn't make your original example compile until used with a constexpr `SparseArray` object.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Now I understand tha missed one most essential thing in the topic. Added to topic.

Comment: @ВладимирН, That's covered in the answer. You can't expect compile-time results from a function called on a runtime object. You're going to have to take a look at what you're giving the compiler to work with.

Comment: I made `constexpr SparseArray<int, 3> array(1, 2, 3);` but still can not call `someMethod()` method. I suppose compiler have all the info he needs to call this method. But, it doesn't work: `error: passing 'const SparseArray<int, 3ul>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     array.someMethod();`

Comment: Oh. I added `const` to method and it is became better. But still this string `auto seq2 = std::integer_sequence<ElementType, get<0>()>{};` leads to `error: 'this' is not a constant expression`

Comment: @ВладимирН, Yes, `constexpr` functions like `someMethod` are required to be usable at compile-time and runtime. As of C++17, there isn't a really great option for forcing only compile-time evaluation. You can't yet use objects of custom types as template arguments and `constexpr!` isn't merged in as of writing.