# Creating an index_sequence of N zeros

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I've been trying to write a `zero_sequence` type which either creates an `index_sequence` of a specified number of zeros or uses an existing 
`index_sequence` as to produce a new one with the same number of values, but all zero. I'm perplexed as to why this is happening:

```
template<typename> struct zero_sequence;
template<size_t...I> 
struct zero_sequence<index_sequence<I...>> : index_sequence<(I*0u)...>{};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

  using A  = index_sequence<0,1,2,3,4>;
  using B  = make_index_sequence<5>;
  using A0 = zero_sequence<A>;
  using B0 = zero_sequence<B>;

  A a;  B b; 

  cout <<< std::is_same<A,B>::value << endl; // is false

  A0 a0; 
  B0 b0;  // < error implicit instantiation of undefined template
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the two cases are different (on Mac Clang llvm 9.0.0).

In case it is relevant to explaining this behavior, I am using the following implementation of `index_sequence` and `make_index_sequence` in C++11 [I think I got it from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/2308288):

```
template<typename Integer, Integer... I>
struct integer_sequence {
  using type = integer_sequence;
  using value_type = Integer;
  static constexpr size_t size() noexcept { return sizeof...(I); }
};

template<size_t... Ints> using index_sequence = integer_sequence<size_t, Ints...>;

template <typename,typename> struct _merge_and_renumber;

template <size_t... I1, size_t... I2>
struct _merge_and_renumber<index_sequence<I1...>,index_sequence<I2...>> 
  : index_sequence<I1..., (sizeof...(I1)+I2)...> {};

template <size_t N>
struct make_index_sequence
  : _merge_and_renumber<typename make_index_sequence<N/2>::type,
                        typename make_index_sequence<N - N/2>::type> {};

template<> struct make_index_sequence<0> : index_sequence<> {};
template<> struct make_index_sequence<1> : index_sequence<0> {};
```

Comment: the only error I get from this is the `<<<` after `cout`? (gcc 7.2 and clang 4.0 both work for me)

Comment: actually wait, integer_sequence was added in `C++14`, are you actually using C++11?

Comment: live examples: [gcc-5.2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zvqaRtRwWg0gU9Fp) and [clang 3.5](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wtAgBTM0XlEkq08m)

Comment: Yes, the code at the bottom is a `C++11` implementation of `integer_sequence` and `index_sequence`.

Comment: Ah of course, sorry. It seems the problem is just with make_index_sequence implementation. The type of `make_index_sequence` won't be an `index_sequence`, it's a new class type you've defined

Comment: [this one looks right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49672613/1013719)

Comment: Odd, because the `make_index_sequence` either inherits from `index_sequence` or from `_merge_and_renumber`, which, in turn, `inherits from index_sequence`

Comment: @RyanHaining, I replaced the make_index_sequence implementation with the one you linked to and the code now works correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Right, but they are still different types. Templates type matching doesn't work like function overload resolution, it has to be an exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a `zero_sequence` completely different: not a `struct` but a `using` based over a `decltype()`, a `std::declval()` and a only declared helper function (following the `std::declval()` example.

I mean... if you define the following helper function

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto zeHelper (index_sequence<Is...> const &)
   -> decltype( index_sequence<(Is,0u)...>{} );
```

`zero_sequence` can be defined as

```
template <typename T>
using zero_sequence = decltype(zeHelper(std::declval<T>()));
```

and you can declate both `a0` and `b0`

```
A0 a0; 
B0 b0; // now works
```

and compile without problems also

```
static_assert( std::is_same<A0, B0>::value, "!" );
```

> I'm perplexed as to why this is happening [...] I don't understand why the two cases are different

The problem with your `zero_sequence` template struct specialization

```
template<size_t...I> 
struct zero_sequence<index_sequence<I...>> : index_sequence<(I*0u)...>{};
```

is that there is also the generic version (unimplemented, but there is)

```
template<typename> struct zero_sequence;
```

So when you use a `index_sequence` as template parameter for `zero_sequence`, the implemented specialization matches and is selected.

But when you use a `make_index_sequence`, that inherit from `index_sequence` and can be converted to a `index_sequence` but isn't exactly a `index_sequence`, the specialization doesn't match and the generic (unimplemented) version of `zero_sequence` is selected.

Passing through a function, the `zeHelper()` that I propose or something similar, avoids this problem because a `make_index_sequence` is convertible to a `index_sequence`.