# Handling NULL while using std::move on the tuples

Tags: c++11, stdtuple

I am working with the below sample code.

```
auto kernarg = hip_impl::make_kernarg(kernel, std::tuple<Args...>{std::move(args)...});
.
.
.

template <typename... Formals, typename... Actuals>
inline impl::kernarg make_kernarg(
void (*kern)(Formals...), std::tuple<Actuals...> actuals) {
static_assert(sizeof...(Formals) == sizeof...(Actuals),
    "The count of formal arguments must match the count of actuals.");

if (sizeof...(Formals) == 0) return {};

std::tuple<Formals...> to_formals{std::move(actuals)};
impl::kernarg kernarg;
kernarg.reserve(sizeof(to_formals));
.
.
.
```

when NULL is present as one of the arguments in actuals, the code gives error as below (type of NULL is long int in this case).

```
grid_launch.hpp:96:28: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::tuple<float *, int, int *>'
std::tuple<Formals...> to_formals{std::move(actuals)};
                       ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
grid_launch.hpp:165:30: 
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 
'impl::make_kernarg<float *, int, int *, float *, int, long>' 
requested here
auto kernarg = impl::make_kernarg(kernel, std::tuple<Args...> 
{std::move(args)...});
```

As seen, the expected type of parameter is int* here, but NULL is of type long, so the error.

In such cases, How can we find which argument is NULL in the tuple actuals and fetch it and typecast or do something to match it with the exact type in the tuple to_formals (Here its int*, but it can be any pointer to integral type depending on the situation). Do we need to fetch all the values from to_formals and actuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't a problem of `std::move`.

The problem is that C++ is a static typed language. So if you have an assignment of type

```
std::tuple<Formals...> to_formals{std::move(actuals)};
```

where a type of the `decltype(actuals)` tuple is `long`, the compiler can't evaluate, compile time, if the long value is zero, so convert it to a pointer of same other type, or not.

For this type of problems, C++11 introduced a type for null pointers (`std::nullptr_t`) and a new keyword to avoid `NULL` (`nullptr`).

So, by example, if you have a function as follows

```
template <typename ... Formals, typename ... Actuals>
void foo (void(*)(Formals...), std::tuple<Actuals...> act)
 {
   std::tuple<Formals...> frm { std::move(act) };
 }
```

and given a function `void(float *, int, int *)`

```
void bar (float *, int, int *)
 { }
```

calling with `NULL`

```
foo(&bar, std::make_tuple(&f0, 0, NULL)); // compilaton error
```

you get a compilation error (the same of your question, I suppose) but using `nullptr`

```
foo(&bar, std::make_tuple(&f0, 0, nullptr)); // compile
```

If you really want/need use `NULL` instead of `nullptr`, the best I can imagine is cast every element of the `actuals` tuple to the type of the formals tuple; something as follows

```
template <typename ... Formals, typename ... Actuals, std::size_t ... Is>
void foo_helper (void(*)(Formals...), std::tuple<Actuals...> act,
                 std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 {
   std::tuple<Formals...> frm { (Formals)std::get<Is>(act)... };
 }

template <typename ... Formals, typename ... Actuals>
void foo (void(*pfunc)(Formals...), std::tuple<Actuals...> act)
 {
   foo_helper(pfunc, act, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Actuals)>{});
 }
```

Now compile also

```
foo(&bar, std::make_tuple(&f0, 0, NULL));
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> can you please elaborate on the index_sequence being used. Also, do we really need a helper function or it can be done without that

The indexes of the `std::index_sequence` are needed to extract the values form the `act` tuple; unfortunately the couple `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence` is introduced in C++14 but, if you need it in C++11, there is a lot of C++11 alternative implementations.

Unfortunately, the indexes sequence in `std::index_sequence` need a `std::make_index_sequence` to be created from a `sizeof...()`, so a function call is needed, so a `foo_helper()` function in needed.

Exception.

If your `act` tuple as **exactly** one element for every type, you can (starting from C++14) simply write

```
std::tuple<Formals...> frm { (Formals)std::get<Actuals>(act)... };
```

directly inside `foo()`, without defining/calling a `foo_helper()`.

But the no-type-collision clause is a big limit, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. can you please elaborate on the index_sequence being used.  Also, do we really need a helper function or it can be done without that.

Comment: @SatyanveshD - answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think we get exactly one element for every type in the act tuple, say we might get 2 elements with the type int. so i have to use this helper function. So the rest of the code including to_formals should be put inside the helper or it can still be continued in the actual function.

Comment: @SatyanveshD - there are many `std::make_index` sequence like around there; I'm egocentric so I remember an [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49672613/6022656) that I think (I hope) is clear explaining how can works a simple (but not optimal: it's linear where can be logarithmic) alternative implementation. About exception, you've got the point: if there are two `int` (or two `long`, or two `int *`, etc) in the `Actuals` list, you get an error.

Comment: @SatyanveshD - I suppose the rest of the code could be in the helper function but you can play a lot with this point. By example, the helper function can be dedicated only to create `to_formals`, returning it as a value.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to use your code and get it working. But I want to take a look at my answer containing the modified code, and let me know if any improvements can be done. Especially the helper method and the usage of indexSequence and makeIndexSequence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my modified code looks like, which seem to be working. But had to add so much code just to handle the NULL case.

```
auto kernarg = hip_impl::make_kernarg(kernel, std::tuple<Args...>{std::move(args)...});
.
.
.     
template <std::size_t ...>
struct indexSequence
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper : public indexSequenceHelper<N-1U, N-1U, Next...>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = indexSequence<Next ... >; };

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequence = typename indexSequenceHelper<N>::type;

template <typename ... Formals, typename ... Actuals, std::size_t ... Is>
std::tuple <Formals...> helper (void(*kernel)(Formals...), std::tuple<Actuals...> act,
                 indexSequence<Is...>){
        std::tuple<Formals...> to_formals{ (Formals)std::get<Is>(act)...};
        return to_formals;
}


template <typename... Formals, typename... Actuals>
hip_impl::kernarg make_kernarg(
void (*kernel)(Formals...), std::tuple<Actuals...> actuals) {
static_assert(sizeof...(Formals) == sizeof...(Actuals),
    "The count of formal arguments must match the count of actuals.");

if (sizeof...(Formals) == 0) return {};

std::tuple<Formals...> to_formals;
to_formals = helper(kernel, actuals, makeIndexSequence<sizeof...(Actuals)>{});

hip_impl::kernarg kernarg;
kernarg.reserve(sizeof(to_formals));
.
.
.
}
```